# How can I call a function inside event with "this"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic4

How can I call the function inside of this event?

```
myfunction() {
  alert('bla bla!');
}
this.map.on('moveend', function() {
  console.log('moveend :: ' + this.getCenter());
  this.myfunction(); // => ERROR TypeError: this.myfunction is not a function
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```js
this.map.on('moveend', () => {
  console.log('moveend :: ' + this.getCenter());
  this.myfunction();
});
```

That should work.

Note: The issue you're facing here is [scope](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript). I would suggest doing some reading, it's a valuable concept to understand.

Comment: If OP needs more info about what the difference is between a "function" and an "arrow function". I'd suggest checking out [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I will have an error with "this.getCenter()" => Property 'getCenter' does not exist on type 'HomePage'. 
:/

Comment: It is resolved (by adding the following parameter)
this.map.on('moveend', ($event) => {
      console.log('moveend :: ' + $event.target.getCenter());
      this.myfunction();
});

Thank you very much ^^